# Hide page background via javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this basic page structure:

```
<head>
...
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="template.css" media="screen" />
</head>

<body>
...
</body>
```

The page background image is set in template.css file:

```
body {
...
    background-image: url("../images/texture.jpg");
}
```

When the page is loading, I see my background first, then the other content is displayed. I want to show the entire page all at once. For this, I've added:

```
<style type="text/css">
body {
    visibility: hidden;
}
</style>
```

to the <head>...</head> section and then:

```
<body onload="document.body.style.visibility='visible'">
```

to my body tag hoping that the entire body (with its background) will be originally hidden and displayed at once when the entire page is ready. However this does not happen. I still see my background image before the other content when I refresh the page.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You could hide the whole page and "show" it after the dom-ready element is fired up, its a farily easy piece of work :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <style>
            body{
                background: green;
                display: none;
            }
        </style>
        <div id="lotsandlotsofstuff">[...]</div>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
        <script>  
        $('document').ready(function(){
            $('body').fadeIn();
        });
        </script> 
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: If there is a javascript error on a page or the user has javascript disabled, the page will never get shown.